# oracle-javamail csv attachment download

Tags: java, oracle, email

Recently I ran into a problem when downloading CSVs from my email via oracle-javamail.  I've found that the first one works fine (coming from a mainframe server) however the second csv attachment seems to come over as "application/vnd.ms-excel" when it is clearly a .csv file just like the other file that downloads perfectly fine.

I'm using the same bit of code on both of them and can't find any information on this issue.

If I fwd that email to myself I can magically download the attachment without any problems.  Any help would be appreciated.  Once I get this working another daily task is automated!

```
    if(content instanceof java.lang.String){
    //emailBody = (String)content;
} else if(content instanceof Multipart){
    System.out.println("is Multipart");
    Multipart mp = (Multipart)content;
    for (int j=0; j < mp.getCount(); j++) {
        Part part = mp.getBodyPart(j);
        String disposition = part.getDisposition();
        if (disposition == null) {
            // Check if plain
            MimeBodyPart mbp = (MimeBodyPart)part;
            if (mbp.isMimeType("text/plain")) {                             
                //emailBody += (String)mbp.getContent();
            } else {                            
                // Special non-attachment cases here of 
                // image/gif, text/html, ...                                
                String fileName = decodeName(part.getFileName());
                File savedir = new File(path+"\\"+fileName);
                saveFile(savedir, part);                                
            }
        } else if ((disposition != null) &&  
                (disposition.equals(Part.ATTACHMENT) || disposition.equals(Part.INLINE))){
                // Check if plain
                MimeBodyPart mbp = (MimeBodyPart)part;
                if (mbp.isMimeType("text/plain")) {                             
                    System.out.println("has disp of plain");
                    //emailBody += (String)mbp.getContent();
                } else {                            
                    System.out.println("has disp of else");
                    String fileName = decodeName(part.getFileName());
                    File savedir = new File(path+"\\"+fileName);
                    saveFile(savedir, part);                    
                }
        }
    }
}
else{
    System.out.println(message.getContentType());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it appears that java knows what type of email it is receiving it turns out that it doesn't.  Since this isn't a standard type it will return it as an Input Stream.  I was able to see the contents of the file with the below code.

Also note that the only reason this came over as a application/vnd.ms-excel file type is because the body of the email was empty.

```
        InputStream emailIn = (InputStream) message.getContent();
    Scanner s = null;
    try{
        s = new Scanner(emailIn).useDelimiter("\\A");
    while(s.hasNext())
        System.out.println(s.next());
    }
    finally{
        s.close();
    }
```